# Unable to display String from Intent

Tags: java, android

At the moment when running I get only one text displayed `Wrong_answer`.

```
public class AnswerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_answer);
    TextView textViewDisplayResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view_display_result);

    textViewDisplayResult.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("KEY_ALL_CHECKED"));
    textViewDisplayResult.setText(getIntent().getBooleanExtra("KEY_ANSWER", false)?R.string.Good_answer:R.string.Wrong_answer);
}
```

**POST UPDATE**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static int NUMBER_OF_QUESTIONS = 3;
static boolean[] answer = new boolean[NUMBER_OF_QUESTIONS];
static boolean[] checked = new boolean[NUMBER_OF_QUESTIONS];
static boolean[] isAnswered = new boolean[NUMBER_OF_QUESTIONS];

 final Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AnswerActivity.class);

buttonCheckAnswer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (!allAnswersChecked())
                intent.putExtra("KEY_ALL_CHECKED", R.string.text_not_checked);

            else if (checkAnswers())
                intent.putExtra("KEY_ANSWER", R.string.Good_answer);

            else
                intent.putExtra("KEY_ANSWER", R.string.Wrong_answer);

            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
public static void checkSelected() {
    for (boolean radioChecked : checked) {
        if (radioChecked) {
            buttonCheckAnswer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            break;
        }
    }
}


private boolean checkAnswers() {
    for (boolean radioAnswer : answer) {
        if (!radioAnswer) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

private boolean allAnswersChecked() {
    for (boolean radioAnswer : isAnswered) {
        if (!radioAnswer) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

and AnswerActivity

```
public class AnswerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_answer);
    TextView textViewDisplayResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view_display_result);

    textViewDisplayResult.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("KEY_ALL_CHECKED"));
    textViewDisplayResult.setText(getIntent().getBooleanExtra("KEY_ANSWER", false)?getString(R.string.Good_answer):getString(R.string.Wrong_answer));

}
```

}

Comment: are you aware that your first setText is getting overridden by your second setText? learn concatenation and after do some setText

Comment: How to solve it? Please help.

Comment: how are you sending data ?...

Comment: @rafsanahmad007, what do you mean exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Second `setText` will overwrite your first `setText` value.

```
....
String x = getIntent().getExtras().getString("KEY_ALL_CHECKED");
textViewDisplayResult.setText(getIntent().getBooleanExtra("KEY_ANSWER", false) ? x +" "+ R.string.Good_answer: x +" "+ R.string.Wrong_answer);
```

Comment: Your code Roljhon doesn't show any errors but now when running onces the 'checkAnswerButton` is pressed I get none of the answers above but `NULL 2131099670`

Comment: Roljhon, I had a look at your code again - do I have to put something in `" "`?

Comment: @Ramona no, you don't need, it will just put a space.

Comment: Shi.., I can't get it working :( Why do I still get only one value `Wrong answers` :(

Comment: @Ramona probably the issue is not from this specifc code block, but from something that we don't know you didn't posted, better post your entire code that sends the strings to this intent and your entire activity code as well. that might help us helping you

Comment: @Ramona your `intent` declaration is no where to be found in your main activity class

Comment: Sorry I missed this. Added just now.

Comment: @Ramona I've told you that you should not use double `setText`, append or concatenation, use my example and make sure you correctly passing your `KEY_ALL_CHECKED` in the answer activity. It seems that your problem is in your main acvity specifically in your if statements debug from there and check if those conditions were really met accordingly

Comment: Ok, Roljhon. I applied your code. Can you please tell me any webside where I can get some specific info on how to debug? I know how to use it but I have no idea how to read the info given from debugging

Comment: @Ramona there's no specific website for it, it's more on experience. Join this chatroom http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19132/java-and-android-era, there are a lot of people which is ready to help you

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I can't join chat yet coz haven't got 20 reputation.

Comment: How come that when I use your code I don't get any of my answers but `NULL 2131099670`? :(

Comment: @Ramona wrap `R.string.Wrong_answer` and `R.string.Good_answer` with `getString()` because i think they are boolean expressions and for the NULL, it's because your `KEY_ALL_CHECKED` is not being pass to your answer activity, try putting any values on `x`. See if it will show up

Answer (score 0):

textViewDisplayResult will always overwrite.
If you want both to display in same textView you just need to append the text like below:

```
textViewDisplayResult.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("KEY_ALL_CHECKED"));
textViewDisplayResult.append(getIntent().getBooleanExtra("KEY_ANSWER", false)?getString(R.string.Good_answer):getString(R.string.Wrong_answer));
```

This will display your both result in same textView.

Comment: Thank you Amit. Eventually I want three texts to display in same textView - `"KEY_ALL_CHECKED" ,"Good answers" and "Wrong answer"` .Your code gives me error `append in TextView cannot be applied`. Can you help, please?

Comment: Now it crashes when I press `buttonCheckAnswer` :(

Comment: what is crash log can you please share, as it seems you have some different issue

Comment: Its not possible, please restart your android monitor as i only changes to getString() which returns you string, will better help you if you can share your crash log.

Comment: Ok. one second. I will open a.studio again

Comment: Sorry friend i don't think so from this log anyone can help you  here.